# How can get the last post date of the user?

Tags: posts, users, date

I want to get the last post date was written by the user and here's the code that I have made but it's not working:

```
function get_user_last_post_date( $user_id ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby ' => 'post_date'
    );
    $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    $last_date = '';
    if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $last_date = $latest_posts;
    }

    return $last_date;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample code the `$latest_posts` is an instance of WP_Query class.
If you want to get the latest post's date, you should do this:

```
$latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

$last_date = '';
if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
   $latest_posts->the_post();
   $last_date = get_the_date();
}

return $last_date;
```

Comment: I got a error: Notice: Trying to get property 'post_date' of non-object

Comment: Your code is not correct it's not getting the latest post date was written by the user

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my code. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It's getting the date of the first post not the latest post.

Comment: @John, WP_Query has default values for `order` and `orderby` parameters, and it's default values will sort posts by date in a way that the latest posts come first. So remove these two parameters from `$args`

Comment: I have removed them and the same result :( it's working with you?

Comment: @John Please tell me what do you mean about latest post? The newest or the oldest?

Comment: Newest posts Had1z

Comment: @John With `'orderby' => 'date'` and `'order' => 'DESC'` it should give you the latest post. Please read the documentations: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters